# Can't install numpy in PyCharm

Tags: numpy, pip, pycharm, python-idle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q55IV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPiRO.png)
I can't install numpy via PyCharm and can import numpy in PyCharm but I did install numpy in IDLE. how can I solve it

Comment: One installs 3rd party packages, with pip, to a particular python installation.  IDLE has nothing to do with installing such packages, or with importing them.  Which means it does not get in the way.  I cannot say anything about PyCharm.  I suspect that he answer to your question is contained in responses to similar questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.